# Why when the components of this script, do they run fine but do not work when pieced together? There may just be a problem with it all together

Tags: lua, roblox

This script is from Roblox Studio and is in Lua. I have tried using separate scripts but when I do, they don't work because of the bool value. The scripts seem either not to respond to it or it just doesn't update correctly.  [I have attached the picture of the hierarchy from ROBLOX Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHzSA.jpg). I am reasonably to new to Lua but I am familiar with the basic concepts. I also know the Roblox Studio Interface deeply. If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
local lockvalue = script.Parent.Lockdown.Value
lockvalue = false
local RobBank = script.Parent["Rob Bank"]
local ClickDetector = RobBank:WaitForChild("ClickDetector")
local BillboardCXZ = RobBank:WaitForChild("BillboardGui")
local Billboard = BillboardCXZ:WaitForChild("TextLabel")
local emergencylight1 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight.Toggle.Value
local emergencylight2 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight2.Toggle.Value
local emergencylight3 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight3.Toggle.Value
local alarm1 = script.Parent.Parent.Alarm1.AlarmSound
local alarm2 = script.Parent.ParentAlarm2.AlarmSound
local Notif1 = script.Parent.NotifcationScreen.SurfaceGui.Frame.Visible
local Notif2 = script.Parent.NotifcationScreen.SurfaceGui.Frame.TextButton.MouseButton1Click
print ("Values Loaded.")



local function lock()
    print ("LOCK FUNCTION ACTIVATED")
    emergencylight1 = true
    emergencylight2 = true
    emergencylight3 = true
    alarm1:play()
    alarm2:play()
    lockvalue = true
    Notif1 = true
end

local function unlock()
    print ("UNLOCK FUNCTION ACTIVATED")
    emergencylight1 = false
    emergencylight2 = false
    emergencylight3 = false
    alarm1.stop()
    alarm2:stop()
    lockvalue = false
    Notif1 = false
end


Notif2:Connect(function()

unlock()
print ("Unlocked Via Override")

end)




RobBank.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(Player)
print ("Functioning")
if Player and Player.Character then
print ("Milestone 2")
        if lockvalue == false then
    print ("After Lock Value")
          if Player.Team == game.Teams.Criminal then
            print ("Team Check")        
            local clicks = Player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")["Bounty"]
            clicks.Value = clicks.Value + 500
            local clicks2 = Player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")["Cash"]
            clicks2.Value = clicks2.Value + 2500
            Billboard.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1,0,0)
            lock()
            wait(60)
            unlock()
            Billboard.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0,1,0)
          else
                print("Player Is not On Crim team.")
                Billboard.Text = ("You are on the Wrong Team!")
                wait(3)
                Billboard.Text = ("Steal Cash")
          end

        else
            Billboard.Text = ("Already been recently robbed!")
            wait(3)
            Billboard.Text = ("Steal Cash")
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: any error messages? what is "they don't work because of the bool value" supposed to mean?

Comment: The bool value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua, a variable can be a reference to a table which has children (key/value pairs):

```
local myTable = { }
myTable.myKey = true
```

However, if you refer to a single child (by its key) then it will evaluate and pass only the resulting value into the variable (*not a reference to the key itself*).

```
local newVar = myTable.myKey
print(newVar)         -- true
newVar = false
print(newVar)         -- false
print(myTable.myKey)  -- true, because we never changed myKey
```

So in the following statement, emergencylight1 is probably the value 'true' or 'false' rather than being a reference to the property itself.

```
local emergencylight1 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight.Toggle.Value
```

#### Recommendation

Ensure your variables are references to an actual table, and then refer to a child of that table (by its key) when assigning a new value.

```
local emergencylighttoggle1 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight.Toggle
local emergencylighttoggle2 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight2.Toggle
local emergencylighttoggle3 = script.Parent.Parent.EmergencyLight3.Toggle

local function lock()
    emergencylighttoggle1.Value = true
    emergencylighttoggle2.Value = true
    emergencylighttoggle3.Value = true
end


local function unlock()
    emergencylighttoggle1.Value = false
    emergencylighttoggle2.Value = false
    emergencylighttoggle3.Value = false
end
```